# C++ EXC_BAD_ACCESS Error in Prim's Algorithm Implementation

Tags: c++, xcode, exc-bad-access

I am working on implementing Prim's algorithm in C++ to find the Minimum Spanning Tree (MST). However, I've encountered a persistent "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" error that occurs at the line key[src] = 0;.

The code reads input from a text file, e.g., "example.txt."
Each line of the file begins with a vertex number. Following the vertex number are pairs of numbers, xij is the jth neighbor of vertex i (vertex labels are 0 through n), and wij is the weight of that edge.

```
0 x01 w01 x02 w02 x03 w03...
1 x11 w11 x12 w12 x13 w13 ...
n xn1 wn1 xn2 wn2 xn3 wn3 ...
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <queue>
#include <utility>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

// iPair ==> Integer Pair
typedef pair<int, double> iPair;  // Changed to support double weights

// This class represents a weighted graph using adjacency list representation
class Graph {
    int V;  // Number of vertices

    // In a weighted graph, we need to store vertex and weight pair for every edge
    list<pair<int, double>> *adj;

public:
    Graph(int V);  // Constructor

    // Function to add an edge to the graph
    void addEdge(int u, int v, double w);  // Changed to support double weights

    // Print MST using Prim's algorithm
    void primMST();
};

// Allocates memory for the adjacency list
Graph::Graph(int V) {
    this->V = V;
    adj = new list<iPair>[V];
}

void Graph::addEdge(int u, int v, double w) {  // Changed to support double weights
    adj[u].push_back(make_pair(v, w));
    adj[v].push_back(make_pair(u, w));
}

void Graph::primMST() {
    // Create a priority queue to store vertices that
    // are being primMST. This is a min-heap.
    priority_queue<iPair, vector<iPair>, greater<iPair>> pq;

    int src = 0;  // Taking vertex 0 as source

    // Create a vector for keys and initialize all keys as infinite
    vector<double> key(V, numeric_limits<double>::max());

    // To store parent array which in turn stores MST
    vector<int> parent(V, -1);

    // To keep track of vertices included in MST
    vector<bool> inMST(V, false);

    // Insert source itself into the priority queue and initialize its key as 0.
    pq.push(make_pair(0, src));
    key[src] = 0;

    // Loop until the priority queue becomes empty
    while (!pq.empty()) {
        int u = pq.top().second;
        pq.pop();

        // Ignore vertices that have already been included in MST
        if (inMST[u]) {
            continue;
        }

        inMST[u] = true;  // Include vertex in MST

        // Iterate over all adjacent vertices
        for (auto i = adj[u].begin(); i != adj[u].end(); ++i) {
            int v = (*i).first;
            double weight = (*i).second;

            if (!inMST[v] && key[v] > weight) {
                // Update key of v
                key[v] = weight;
                pq.push(make_pair(key[v], v));
                parent[v] = u;
            }
        }
    }

    // Print MST in the format you specified
    for (int i = 0; i < V; ++i) {
        cout << i << " ";
        for (auto it = adj[i].begin(); it != adj[i].end(); ++it) {
            int v = it->first;
            double weight = it->second;
            if (v == parent[i]) {
                cout << v << " " << weight << " ";
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    ifstream inputFile("example.txt");
    if (!inputFile) {
        cerr << "Failed to open the input file." << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    int V; // Number of vertices
    inputFile >> V;

    Graph g(V);

    int vertex, neighborCount;
    double weight;
    for (int i = 0; i < V; ++i) {
        inputFile >> vertex >> neighborCount;
        for (int j = 0; j < neighborCount; ++j) {
            inputFile >> vertex >> weight;
            g.addEdge(i, vertex, weight);
        }
    }

    g.primMST();

    inputFile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

The input:

```
0 1 8.0 2 5.0

1 0 8.0 2 4.0 3 6.0 4 3.0

2 0 5.0 1 4.0 4 2.0

3 1 6.0 4 5.0 5 1.0

4 1 3.0 2 2.0 3 5.0 5 4.0

5 3 1.0 4 4.0
```

output should be

```
0 2 5.0

1 4 3.0

2 0 5.0 4 2.0

3 5 1.0

4 1 3.0 2 2.0 5 4.0

5 3 1.0 4 4.0
```

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run this code, what did you see? The bug in the shown code is very obvious in a debugger. Do you know how to use a debugger?

Comment: Are you sure that is the correct input? Seems it should have a 5 before the 5 lines of data so `V` isn't 0. If I change that then it crashes in `addEdge` because `v` is out of range. https://godbolt.org/z/5aP8cjcjG Seems suspect that you read into `vertex` twice, especially since it is an `int` and the second read is reading a double from the input.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik , I'm relatively new to using debuggers and might not be fully aware of what to look for in this particular issue. If you could offer specific pointers on what to focus on when using a debugger in the context of the code I've shared, it would be immensely helpful. For instance, are there particular variables or expressions I should watch, or specific breakpoints I should set to identify the root cause of the problem?

Comment: Well, for example, you say that the program crashes at `key[src] = 0;`? Great. Now set a breakpoint on that line. When execution gets there, use your debugger to inspect what the value of `src` is, and how big the vector `key` is. Then, depending on what the results are, figure out the next steps. Unfortunately, there is no cookie-cutter, paint-by-numbers recipe for debugging some random bit of code. One needs to learn how to do this, by analyzing and understanding what the program is doing, and what it should be doing, and what it's actually doing, using a debugger.

Comment: The issues I see are all related to the example input not matching the code. Here is a version that requires the number of lines as the first number in the input and then reads the rest as an index and pairs of vertex/weight. The output doesn't match what you've shown but it does appear to be partially correct. If nothing else it doesn't crash or leak memory. https://godbolt.org/z/e4v6dKnz1

Comment: @Aly `list<pair<int, double>> *adj;` -- There is no need to use pointers here.   You have `#include <vector>`, so why not use it?  This could be simply `std::vector<list<pair<int, double>>> adj;`, and then `Graph::Graph(int V) : adj(V){}`.  Then `V` is no longer needed as a member variable, since `adj.size()` knows how many lists were created.  That would remove the memory leaks and any manual memory management. [See this](https://godbolt.org/z/ePhEn6oqe).

Comment: Once those changes are made, then use `at()` instead of `[]` when accessing the vector's elements.  If you go out-of-bounds, an `std::out_of_range` exception will be thrown.